# loadNibNamed loads to different IBOutlets?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, iboutlet

I have a very weird problem and has not been able to solve it yet.

This class is defined:

```
@interface EngineViewController : UIViewController
{
}
@property (nonatomic,readonly) IBOutlet GameView* vGameView;
@property (nonatomic,readonly) IBOutlet MainMenu* vMainMenu;
@property (nonatomic,readonly) IBOutlet CountryOverlay* vCountryOverlay;
@end
```

In init method I have this code:

```
if (![[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EngineViewController" owner:self options:nil])
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to load menu nib!");
    return NO;
}

// init
[self.view addSubview:vMainMenu];
```

The problem is, that vMainMenu is nil, vGameView is 0x1 and MainMenu class instance is assigned to vCountryOverlay (instead of vMainMenu).

Yes, in Xib, I have EngineViewController as File Owner and vMainMenu outlet set to UIView (MainMenu class) + other outlets not set.

I am out of ideas what to try. I tried to create an empty xib, set file owner to EngineViewController and set that vMainMenu outlet again. I have also tried to add a new "dummy" outlet property at the beginning. Tried to call loadNibNamed from a different part of the app, always the same.

But when I created a new, clean project, new nib, set owner, made a few outlets and did the same it worked just fine.

Why would loadNibNamed cause the first outlet to be set to 0x1 and "to offset" others, setting an instance which should be at the current outlet to the next one? Any idea what to try?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Problem was in the (gdb) debugger. It showed wrong data for wrong symbols.
Data was loaded correctly to IBOutlets, crashing problem was somewhere else.
Thanks a lot for trying to help me.

It these situations, try to use NSLog first. :P

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind trying the following declaration for your properties:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet GameView* vGameView;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet MainMenu* vMainMenu;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet CountryOverlay* vCountryOverlay;
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried - the same. I have also tried to use class members only (no properties) but always the same. I guess something in UIKit is damaged at that part of the app. I will try to do the same as soon as app is started...

Comment: I wonder: why are you using loadNibNamed and not letting IB fully instantiate you view controller and all related objects?

Comment: Because I need to load some views dynamically and unload them when no longer needed (to save memory). And it always behaves this way, even when I do that in applicationDidFinish launching! But on a new clean project, it works. Omg...

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController's default init method may be doing some screwy things.
You should use

```
- (id) init {
   self = [self initWithNibNamed:@"EngineViewController" ....];
   if (self) { ... }
   return self;
}
```